# Downloading specific WMS data in QGIS

Tags: download, raster, qgis, wms

for a project I am working on, I would like to characterize the geology of an area around some points in the Czech Republic. Czech geological survey offer their excelent map ([https://micka.geology.cz/en/record/basic/4d01fbc5-f0a0-4a31-9ec5-ebc40a010817]) through the WMS servers which works fine in the QGIS for me. However, there seems to be some issues when I try to calculate anything with the map as all the operations (even simple ones) seem to take hours to compute and never finish doing so.

I was thinking if there is some way how to download the map from the WMS servers. Simply exporting the layer is not a good solution for me this time as it the originial map uses some multicolour symbology for certain geology types. Therefore, the  exported TIFF cannot be used simply as "pixels of colour XY means geology ZW".

[Original data, zoomed in so you can see the symbology of different layers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkUG2.png)

[And the exported TIFF.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHHNC.png)

Is there some easy workaround around this? Or any way how to do it? I am using QGIS (v 3.22.3), but I am also able to use R language if there is a better way how to approach this issue.

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Seems the data is provided only as raster, and you probably needs the vectors for operations. I haven't found any on  http://www.geology.cz. I would either write to authors or digitize those rasters around points of interest.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. But it is not true. I could also work with raster data, but when I try to export them, I have this useless raster as in my example. Anyway, thanks again, writing the authors will be probably the fastest solution.

Comment: WMS doesn't give access to data, only an image representation of it.

Comment: Thank you, that explain a lot of things :) And that is something I did not know before.